# Time.now.beginning_of_week giving two different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get values from a table for a weeks data as below

```
Answer.where("ct_id = ? AND ot_id = ? AND created_at >= ?",16,72,Time.now.beginning_of_week)
```

It fires a query

```
Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `answers`.* FROM `answers` WHERE (ct_id = 16 AND ot_id = 72 AND created_at >= '2016-02-28 18:30:00')
```

time in the above query is '2016-02-28 18:30:00'

But in rails console the value is

> Time.now.beginning_of_week
>    => 2016-02-29 00:00:00 +0530

So which is the correct value and why is it giving two different value when i try it in console.

I know that Time.now.beginning_of_week starts the week from Sunday ie 18th ,but why is that when i do it in console its showing 19th monday.

Hope some one can clarify my doubt on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fire `Time.now.beginning_of_week` in console it gives time in you local timezone i.e +5.30 (Indian standard time).

All times stored in database are stored in utc.

> ```
> Answer.where("ct_id = ? AND ot_id = ? AND created_at >= ?",16,72,Time.now.beginning_of_week)
> ```

When we use `Time.now.beginning_of_week` in above query, it will get converted to utc as we need to compare with record stored in db, which is in utc.

To convert below time 2016-02-29 00:00:00 +0530 into utc time, we have to subtract -5.30 from it as it is +5.30 from utc.

```
Time in utc = 2016-02-29 (00:00:00 - 5.30)
Time in utc = 2016-02-29 18.30
```

Update:

If you want to get beginning_of_week in utc. You can do following in rails 4. Not sure whether this works on rails 3.

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week.to_time(:utc) # o/p 2016-02-29 00:00:00 UTC
```